# DIY antenna voltage output

Tags: voltage, antenna

If I make a basic 2.4 GHz antenna like from this link (http://www.wikihow.com/Design-a-Simple-Antenna) and connect signal pin and ground pin to oscilloscope what would I see ? I mean will there any AC voltage if so , what will be level of it milli , micro or pico ?

Comment: What sort of scope do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in the range of microvolts. And that AC signal will be at 2.4GHz, so you'll ned a very expensive scope to see it as a sinewave (bandwidth at least 5GHz).

Comment: Do you mean sample rate > 5Gs/s?

Comment: @DaveTweed I was thinking of a good old analog oscilloscope with a CRT... but yes, 5Gsamples/s for one of those new-fangled digital scopes with pixels on the display.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how close you are to a transmitting device, the RF level will probably be around -50 or -60 dBm, which corresponds to around 500 uV.  And you're going to need a scope with at least 2 or 3 GHz of bandwidth in order to look at it, which will not come cheap.